# Batch to execute 7zip to create a zip with password and put date into filename

Tags: batch, batch-file, 7-zip

I've installed Z-zip on my system and created a .batch file like this, that allows me to create a zip file protected by password:

```
@echo off

C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z a -r -pZampa “%DATE:/=.%%TIME::=.%Tablas.zip" 
TPV.accde

pause
```

This code is barely perfect, but something is wrong, as system shows a screen with an error like this:

```
 "C:\Program" Is not recognized as an internal or external command a code"
```

Any idea of what could be going wrong?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfeeV.jpg)

Comment: `“` is not a valid quote character in batch. It should be `"`

Comment: The path to 7zip contains  a space and has to be put in double quotes (the right ones `"` ).